# After upgrade Artiffactory OSS from 6.12.2 to 7.16.3 Artifactory isn't accessible anymore

Tags: artifactory

In the migration.log the upgrade seems to succeeded. Artifactory service is started, but i can't login anymore with LDAP authenticated user in MS AD and also no local user.

I don't know what to do.

Is there anyone who can help me please?

Comment: can you share more information about how the upgrade was performed? in addition, do you see any errors in the Artifactory log files?

Comment: Hi, the migration seemed to finshed successfully, but i hesitate, because the directory structure is not right. I am going to run the migration again carefully. If there are issues again i ask a question again. Thank you for your reply @Dror Bereznitsky